# Why set empty string as null in reactive form become empty string

Tags: angular, typescript, events, directive

I'm trying to convert every string input to null upon cahnge. 
So i create a directive to listen on every change and assign null to empty string.

And here is the HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="mt-4 p-2" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input nbInput fullWidth fieldSize="small" shape="semi-round" formControlName="AuthorityNum" EmptyToNull>
</form>
```

Here is the directive code:

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, ElementRef } from 
'@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[EmptyToNull]'
})
export class NullValueDirective {

 constructor() {
 }

 @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.value']) onKeyDowns(value) {
 if (value === '') {
  value = null;
  console.log(value) // print: null
  }
 }
}
```

It looks like it change the value to null

But when i submit the form and inspect the form.value it appears as empty string again.

why?

**Update**:

Here is my submit function:

```
onSubmit() {
 // TODO: Send to server
  this.form.value.AuthorityNum === '' // true
  }
```

Here is the code at stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ilcg7y

Comment: Can you add your submit function? value is a local variable in your host listener, so changing the value inside wont change anything outside.

Comment: I think you need to bind the value returned from your directive to the respective form element.

Comment: But still looks like the value isn't being set to your form. Can you create a stackblitz for this?

Comment: You right. i updated the post.

Comment: I added stackblitz to the post

Comment: I see alot of examples how to do it with template approach but in with Model approch,

Comment: Why exactly are you using this directive in the first place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199362/discussion-between-user384496-and-nicholas-k).

Comment: @user384496 have you tried `AuthorityNum: null,` this if i understand you problem currectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code:

1. The directive needs to emit the value back so that can be *bound* to the respective form control:

   ```
   export class NullValueDirectiveDirective {

      @Output('EmptyToNull') response = new EventEmitter<string>();

      @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyDowns(event: KeyboardEvent) {
         this.response.emit(null);
      }
   }
   ```
2. Next on your template you need to bind to the *emitted* value:

   ```
   <input  formControlName="AuthorityNum" 
   (EmptyToNull) = "form.controls.AuthorityNum.value = $event">
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Directive code:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({ selector: '[EmptyToNull]' })
export class EmptyToNullDirective {
  constructor(@Self() private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyDowns(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.ngControl.value?.trim() === '') {
        this.ngControl.reset(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<input nbInput fullWidth fieldSize="small" shape="semi-round" formControlName="AuthorityNum" EmptyToNull>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your aim using the EmptyToNull directive.

If you're trying to avoid empty values to be passed in the form, you can better use validators when you build the form in your ts:

```
this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
               date: [''],
               AuthorityNum: ['', [Validators.required]],
            });
```

See more on validators: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators

When submitting the form, you can also check the values fullfill the validators you've set:

```
 onSubmit() {
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(field => {
       let control = this.form.get(field);
               control.markAsTouched({
                   onlySelf: true
               });
               control.updateValueAndValidity();
       });
 }
```

Also you can try on the following approaches in your TS when submitting the form or detecting changes in the form:

```
this.form.reset({
        date: { value: '' },
        AuthorityNum: { value: null }
});
```

Or even applied in your directive:

```
this.form.controls['AuthorityNum'].setValue(null);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have a very large form with nested dynamic inputs. The form is for testing so i need the client to be able to send empty string as well as null so validators would not help me as null is valid for that matter. I can loop on all property as you did in your post and check for empty string and assign null but i dont know how to loop on all the property as part of them is array with their on nested property..

Comment: If you know which fields accept arrays as possible values, you can maybe first iterate over each field and then for those fields allowing arrays check how to reach each inner value in the array to tranform it. Debug on "let control".

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to fix this for all your components that doesn't conflict with other `ValueAccessor` and doesn't require adding a directive everywhere.
TLDR:
add this to your AppModule:

```js
    DefaultValueAccessor.prototype.registerOnChange = function (fn: (_: string | null) => void): void {
      this.onChange = (value: string | null) => {
        fn(value === '' ? null : value);
      };
    };
```

To summarize, this is a known issue is angular that reported here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45317
And can't be fixed unless you use this little hack because of much older issue explained here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3009
That prevent overriding the default behavior of angular globally.
Hope it helps.