# FormControl - empty string to null

Tags: angular, forms, angular8, formgroups

is there a possibility to convert a empty string (equals "") to `null`?

I've an input field to override a value in the DB. If i change the value there, it will be stored in the DB - which is great. But if I edit the value (input field) again and remove the text from it, it sends an empty string (eg "") to the DB. But it should send `null` that the source value will be displayed.

**app.component.ts**

```
  readonly titleCtrl = new FormControl()
  readonly descriptionCtrl = new FormControl()
  readonly ageCtrl = new FormControl()

  readonly formGroup = new FormGroup({
    title: this.titleCtrl,
    description: this.descriptionCtrl,
    age: this.ageCtrl,
  })


private fillForm(item: Item): void {
  this.formGroup.setValue(
    {
      title: item.title.overrideValue,
      description: item.description.overrideValue,
      age: item.age.overrideValue,
    },
    { emitEvent: false },
  )
}
```

So what I'd like to reach is if I change something in `title`, and delete it again, it should be `null` instead `""`.

Is there something possible with `valueChanges`?

Comment: Check out this question and answer, is this something like what you're trying to achieve? The person asking the question proposes a solution by using directives. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902512/why-set-empty-string-as-null-in-reactive-form-become-empty-string also, the other answers discuss a different approach by not using directives

Answer (score 3):

```
sanitizeDataBeforeSendToServer(): void {
    const control = this.form.get('nameControl');    
    
    if ((control.value as string)?.trim() === '') {
        control.setValue(null);
    }
}
    
save(): void {
    this.sanitizeDataBeforeSendToServer();
    ....
}
```